# Sort Icon placement

Tags: gui-design, ux-field, sort

I am introducing a sort feature for a few elements such as:

- Name
- Import Code
- Site Priority

I did some Googling and the general concensus is that an icon should always be placed to the left of a text label / title. However, as 'Sort' is a functionality, next to a label / title, I was wondering if it would be better suited to be placed on the right.

[image]

[image]

Could anyone advise on the proper UX practice with this functionality / icon placement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An icon to the left of a unrelated label is clearly not the way to go. If you got the space for it, the best option would be to provide a label to the filter icon.

Essentially, you want a clear distinction between your title and the action, either by different alignment (left, right), size, weight or color (opacity).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, you helped me with my designs and they have been received well by my boss!

Comment: Anytime, glad I helped :)